# Convert Password Protected Zip file to Enc File using c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

I have used the following below code to convert the zip file to enc file but its not working perfectly, please help me to solve this issue

Also if there is any third party tool to convert the zip to enc file please mention the details about it .

Thanks in Advance

```
try
            { 
            string startPath = "";
            string path = @"F:\Augustin\UpTest\Upload\";
            DirectoryInfo objdirinfovikramfile = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            if (objdirinfovikramfile.Exists)
            {
                errorcheck = "a";
                foreach (DirectoryInfo objdirenmvikramfile in objdirinfovikramfile.GetDirectories())
                {
                    string checkvikramfile = "";
                    checkvikramfile = objdirenmvikramfile.Name;
                    startPath = path + checkvikramfile + "\\";
                    string zipPath = path + checkvikramfile + ".zip";

                        string sub = zipPath.Split('\\').Last();

                        Boolean decrypt = false;
                        FileManager obj = new FileManager();

                        Int64 secure_count = 0;

                        while (secure_count <= 3 && !decrypt)

                        {
                            decrypt = obj_viki1.Decryption(zipPath, zipPath.Replace(".zip", ".enc"), "dietcoke1");  //DLL Function
                            secure_count++;
                        }


                        if (secure_count > 3 && !decrypt)
                        {
                            File.Copy(zipPath, path + "\\FAILED\\" + zipPath.Split('\\').Last(),true );
                            File.Copy(zipPath, path + "\\FAILED\\" + zipPath.Split('\\').Last(), true);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.Copy(zipPath, path + "\\SUCCESS\\" + zipPath.Split('\\').Last(), true);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {               
                Error_log("FileProcess Enc: " + errorcheck + "                            ", ex.ToString());
                Application.Exit();
            }
```

Comment: "...not working..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: JohnB sorry i didn't provide any information for your studies, just i said the above code is not suitable to convert the zip file to enc file so I asked if there any third party tool nu

Comment: oh I see.   Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.